# EpiServer PendingPublish is true in PublishedPage event

Tags: episerver, episerver-6

In EpiServer 6, I need to re-index a page whenever it's published. Inside the PublishedPage event handler, I'm checking whether the page is published or not using:

`e.Page.CheckPublishedStatus(PagePublishedStatus.PublishedIgnoreDates)`

This method always returns `false`. The Status property for the page is `Published` but PendingPublish property is `true` and I'm assuming that's the reason why CheckPublishedStatus returns false.

When is the PendingPublish property set to false after a page is published? Is there another event handler I can use for my indexing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but if the **PublishedPage** event fires the event argument will always be a published page.

So, it seems to me the status check is redundant?

Comment: I'm maintaining existing code and indexing function is used in several places. Inside this function is the status check. What do you think I could change this check with?

Comment: Since that event only fires when a page is published, you can be certain it is published. I would index all pages when they're published (simply remove the check) and then to a FilterForVisitor on any search result returned from the search index.

Comment: Note: The name "Published" can be a bit misleading - a page can be published without it being publicly accessible (depending on start/end dates, ACL etc).